# Convert a SQL function into a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I am having trouble converting an UDF into a stored procedure.

Here is what I've got: this is the stored procedure that calls the function (I am using it to search for and remove all UNICODE characters that are not between 32 and 126):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRemoveUNICODE] 
    @FieldList varchar(250) = '', 
    @Multiple int = 0,
    @TableName varchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX), @counter INT = 0

    IF @Multiple > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Field VARCHAR(100)

        SELECT splitdata 
        INTO #TempValue 
        FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@FieldList,',')

        WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempValue) >= 1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT TOP 1 splitdata FROM #TempValue)

            SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @Column + ' = dbo.RemoveNonASCII(' + @Column + ')'

            EXEC (@SQL)
            --print @SQL

            SET @counter = @counter + 1

            PRINT @column + ' was checked for ' + @counter + ' rows.'

            DELETE FROM #TempValue
            WHERE splitdata = @Column
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @Multiple = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @FieldList + ' = dbo.RemoveNonASCII(' + @FieldList + ')'

        EXEC (@SQL)
        --print @SQL

        SET @counter = @counter + 1

        PRINT @column + ' was checked for ' + @counter + ' rows.'
    END
END
```

And here is the UDF that I created to help with the update (RemoveNonASCII):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveNonASCII] 
    (@nstring nvarchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Variables
    DECLARE @Result varchar(max) = '',@nchar nvarchar(1), @position int

    -- T-SQL statements to compute the return value
    set @position = 1
    while @position <= LEN(@nstring)
    BEGIN
        set @nchar = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)
        if UNICODE(@nchar) between 32 and 127
            set @Result = @Result + @nchar
        set @position = @position + 1
        set @Result = REPLACE(@Result,'))','')
        set @Result = REPLACE(@Result,'?','')
    END
    if (@Result = '')
    set @Result = null
    -- Return the result
    RETURN @Result

END
```

I've been trying to convert it into a stored procedure. I want to track how many rows actually get updated when this is run. Right now it just says that all rows, however many I run this on, are updated. I want to know if say only half of them had bad characters. The stored procedure is already set up so that it tells me which column it is looking at, I want to include how many rows were updated. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
DECLARE @Result varchar(max) = '',@nchar nvarchar(1), @position int, @nstring nvarchar(max), @counter int = 0, @CountRows int = 0, @Length int
--select Notes from #Temp where Notes is not null order by Notes OFFSET @counter ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
set @nstring = (select Notes from #Temp where Notes is not null order by Notes OFFSET @counter ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
set @Length = LEN(@nstring)
if @Length = 0 set @Length = 1
-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
set @position = 1
while @position <= @Length
BEGIN
    print @counter
    print @CountRows
    select @nstring
    set @nchar = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)
    if UNICODE(@nchar) between 32 and 127
    begin
        print unicode(@nchar)
        set @Result = @Result + @nchar
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
    if UNICODE(@nchar) not between 32 and 127
    begin
        set @CountRows = @CountRows + 1
    end
    set @position = @position + 1
END
print 'Rows found with invalid UNICODE: ' + convert(varchar,@CountRows)
```

Right now I'm purposely creating a temp table and adding a bunch of notes and then adding in a bunch of invalid characters.

I created a list of 700+ Notes and then updated 2 of them with some invalid characters (outside the 32 - 127). There are a few that are null and a few that are not null, but that doesn't have anything in them. What happens is that I get 0 updates.

> Rows found with invalid UNICODE: 0

Though it does see that the UNICODE for the one that it pulls is 32.

Obviously I'm missing something I just don't see what it is.

Comment: Generally speaking you should do everything you can to avoid to loops. This code has a loop that calls a function that has loops. The performance of this must be pretty rough. You also have a string splitter in there....is that more loops? There is just so much here that needs a total rebuild.

Comment: @SeanLange Why are loops to be avoided?

Comment: Because row by row processing is horribly slow. In sql we do things in sets, not rows.

Comment: @SeanLange: good luck doing this kind of mass-character replacement in a set-based manner that's not also horribly slow. SQL Server 2017 gives us `TRANSLATE`. Prior to that, doing replacement like this efficiently almost requires CLR.

Comment: @JeroenMostert agreed. But this has multiple levels of RBAR which is a pretty good indication that there is some underlying lack of knowledge about set processing.

Comment: Here is a pretty good article about RBAR (row by agonizing row). https://36chambers.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/t-sql-anti-patterns-row-by-agonizing-row-rbar-queries/

Comment: @SeanLange That would be awesome. I'm reading another article I found to [Programming SQL in a Set-Based Way](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/programming-sql-set-based-way) which seems pretty informative with examples in both directions. If you need more information on what I'm attempting here let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a set based solution to handle your bulk replacements. Instead of a slow scalar function this is utilizing an inline table valued function. These are far faster than their scalar ancestors. I am using a tally table here. I keep this as a view on my system like this.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

If you are interested about tally tables here is an excellent article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
create function RemoveNonASCII
(
    @SearchVal nvarchar(max)
) returns table as 
    RETURN
    with MyValues as
    (
        select substring(@SearchVal, N, 1) as MyChar
            , t.N
        from cteTally t 
        where N <= len(@SearchVal)
            and UNICODE(substring(@SearchVal, N, 1)) between 32 and 127 
    )

    select distinct MyResult = STUFF((select MyChar + ''
                    from MyValues mv2
                    order by mv2.N
                    --for xml path('')), 1, 0, '')
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')
        from MyValues mv
    ;
```

Now instead of being forced to call this every single row you can utilize cross apply. The performance benefit of just this portion of your original question should be pretty huge.

I also eluded to your string splitter also being a potential performance issue. Here is an excellent article with a number of very fast set based string splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

The last step here would be eliminate the first loop in your procedure. This can be done also but I am not entirely certain what your code is doing there. I will look closer and see what I can find out. In the meantime parse through this and feel free to ask questions about any parts you don't understand.

Comment: This is awesome, but it'll take me a while to parse through the whole thing. I am reading and testing so don't think I've just abandoned this. Thank you!!

Comment: How would I call this function? I've never used a table valued function. I attempted to use it in my `update` statement, but that did not work.

Comment: You could use a subquery in your update above. I would like to find a better way to do your process though so that you are not doing each update row by row and then column by column.

Comment: The way that I have it setup now is so that I can check multiple columns if I need to, but without having to check all columns. There are usually only 1 or 2 columns that I need to check. Otherwise, it is now using the set based approved. The first SP(spRemoveUNICODE) only loops when there are multiple columns to check and it uses the SplitStrings_Numbers set based function to split the column names string. It calls (hopefully) the RemoveNonASCII_New set based function.

Comment: To test if it works I tried running it like this: `select * from [dbo].[RemoveNonASCII_New]('  05/31/2017㹊潮Ņ᯸ࢹᖈư㹨ƶ槹鎤⻄ƺ綐ڌ⸀ƺ삸)䀤ƍ샄)Ņᛡ鎤ꗘᖃᒨ쬵Ğᘍ鎤ᐜᏰ>֔υ赸Ƹ쳰డ촜)鉀௿촜)쮜)Ἡ屰山舰霡ࣆ 耏Аం畠Ư놐ᓜતᏛ֔Ꮫ֨Ꮫ꯼ᓜƒ 邰఍厰ఆ邰఍드)抉鎤듄)繟Ĺ띨)᯸ࢹ䮸ࣉ᯸ࢹ䮸ࣉ샰)ԌƏŅ֐ᕄ홑Ņᛙ鎤ꗘᖃᒨ᯸ࢹ17 sbn711: E')` and what I get in return is: `  05/31/2017????N???u?z?????????)???)?N??????G????>???????)???)?)???????? ????U?????????? ???????)???)?L?)?????????)?????N???N???????17 sbn711: E` when what I'm expecting to get is `05/31/2017 uz))NG>))) U ))L))NN17 sbn711: E`

Comment: You need to add an N in front of your string so that it is an nvarchar. (N' 05/31...'). Otherwise it will be varchar and unknown characters will be replaced with a question mark which when run through the function is a valid character. :)

Comment: Yep, that did it.

Comment: This has taken the processing time for 5 columns from 65 minutes to 1.5 minutes! I'll post an answer just to show what I've got working now.

Comment: Now do you see why we want to avoid looping? :)

Comment: Yes, that is an insane difference! I should have learned about this sooner!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've got working based on the great help from Sean Lange:

How I call the Stored Procedure:

```
exec spRemoveUNICODE @FieldList='Notes,Notes2,Notes3,Notes4,Notes5',@Multiple=1,@TableName='#Temp'
```

The `#Temp` table is created:

```
create table #Temp (ID int,Notes nvarchar(Max),Notes2 nvarchar(max),Notes3 nvarchar(max),Notes4 nvarchar(max),Notes5 nvarchar(max))
```

Then I fill it with comments from 5 fields from a couple of different tables that range in length from `NULL` to blank (but not null) to 5000 characters.

I then insert some random characters like this:

```
update #Temp
set Notes2 = SUBSTRING(Notes2,1,LEN(Notes2)/2) + N'㹊潮Ņ᯸ࢹᖈư㹨ƶ槹鎤⻄ƺ綐ڌ⸀ƺ삸)䀤ƍ샄)Ņᛡ鎤ꗘᖃᒨ쬵Ğᘍ鎤ᐜᏰ>֔υ赸Ƹ쳰డ촜)鉀௿촜)쮜)Ἡ屰山舰霡ࣆ 耏Аం畠Ư놐ᓜતᏛ֔Ꮫ֨Ꮫ꯼ᓜƒ 邰఍厰ఆ邰఍드)抉鎤듄)繟Ĺ띨)᯸ࢹ䮸ࣉ᯸ࢹ䮸ࣉ샰)ԌƏŅ֐ᕄ홑Ņᛙ鎤ꗘᖃᒨ᯸ࢹ' + SUBSTRING(Notes2,LEN(Notes2)/2-1,LEN(Notes2)/2)
```

I do that for each of the 5 columns.

Here is what the `spRemoveUNICODE` now looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRemoveUNICODE] 
    -- Parameters
    @FieldList varchar(250) = '', 
    @Multiple int = 0,
    @TableName varchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Variables
    declare @SQL varchar(max)
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if @Multiple > 0
    BEGIN
        declare @Field varchar(100)
        select Item into #TempValue from dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers(@FieldList,',')
        while (select count(*) from #TempValue) >= 1
        BEGIN
            declare @Column varchar(100) = (select top 1 Item from #TempValue)
            set @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @Column + ' = tt.Result
                        from ' + @TableName + ' t
                        join (select ID,(select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyResult,''))'',''''),''>)'',''''),'' N>)   N'',''''),'' N   N'','''') 
                                from dbo.RemoveNonASCII_New(' + @Column + ')) Result from ' + @TableName + ') tt on t.ID = tt.ID'

            exec (@SQL)
            --print @SQL --for trouble shooting

            print @column + ' was checked.'
            delete from #TempValue
            from #TempValue
            where Item = @Column
        END
    END
    else if @Multiple = 0
    BEGIN
        set @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @FieldList + ' = tt.Result
                        from ' + @TableName + ' t
                        join (select ID,(select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyResult,''))'',''''),''>)'',''''),'' N>)   N'',''''),'' N   N'','''') 
                                from dbo.RemoveNonASCII_New(' + @FieldList + ')) Result from ' + @TableName + ') tt on t.ID = tt.ID'

        exec (@SQL)
        --print @SQL --for trouble shooting

        print @column + ' was checked.'
    END
END
```

Here is the new `SplitStrings_Numbers` function that splits the column list into the individual column names:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN
   (
       SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
         CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
       FROM dbo.Numbers
       WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
         AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
   );
```

I created the `Numbers` table like this:

```
DECLARE @UpperLimit INT = 1000000;

WITH n AS
(
    SELECT
        x = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM       sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
SELECT Number = x
  INTO dbo.Numbers
  FROM n
  WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND @UpperLimit;

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(Number) 
    WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
GO
```

Then finally the Notes are searched and invalid UNICODE are removed like using the `RemoveNonASSCII_New` function:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[RemoveNonASCII_New]
(
    @SearchVal nvarchar(max)
) returns table as 
    RETURN
    with MyValues as
    (
        select substring(@SearchVal, Number, 1) as MyChar
            , t.Number
        from Numbers t 
        where Number <= len(@SearchVal)
            and UNICODE(substring(@SearchVal, Number, 1)) between 32 and 127 
    )

    select distinct MyResult = STUFF((select MyChar + ''
                    from MyValues mv2
                    order by mv2.Number
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')
        from MyValues mv;
```

The way that I was doing this in my original question took more than 60 minutes to clear all 5 columns. With this new way, it took 1.5 minutes to clear the same 5 columns. There are more than 11000 rows in each column that had the invalid characters added.